# Identical (almost) ELF headers but executables won't run on each other's system

Tags: c, linux, embedded, mips

I'm trying to compile a couple of programs for a little embedded device I own. It's a Little-endian MIPS (mipsel) processor. I retrieved this executable from it via telnet and the builtin ftp client:

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# readelf -h unzip1 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x401cc0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          169960 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x10001007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips2
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         24
  Section header string table index: 23

root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# file unzip1
unzip1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

I then downloaded the MIPSEL version of Debian and I'm running it in QEMU. When I run the retrieved program above I get:

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# ./unzip1
-bash: ./unzip1: No such file or directory
```

Which I understand means it's not the right platform. Stubbornly I compiled a little hello world nonetheless to compare the ELF and file info. My hello world runs fine in Debian MIPSEL but also returns `No such file or directory` on the embedded device. It's `readelf` and `file` output is strikingly similar though:

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# readelf -h hello
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400740
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          3652 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x10001005, noreorder, cpic, o32, mips2
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         10
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         36
  Section header string table index: 35

root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xeb3877062337a3dfd15cc09305691685ac0e8c57, with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, with unknown capability 0x70100 = 0x1040000, stripped
```

I'm trying to better understand how my two systems differ and why the executables won't run on both. Are there any flags I could add to `gcc` to successfully compile for the embedded device?

## More info about the device

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : Ralink SoC
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24K V4.12
BogoMIPS                : 239.10
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

## More info about Debian MIPSEL

*(Binaries compiled on debian-mipsel won't run on the target embedded device)*

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/wansview/devel# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type     : MIPS Malta
processor       : 0
cpu model       : MIPS 24Kc V0.0  FPU V0.0
BogoMIPS        : 1038.33
wait instruction    : yes
microsecond timers  : yes
tlb_entries     : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint : yes, count: 1, address/irw mask: [0x0ff8]
ASEs implemented    : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers  : 0
core            : 0
VCED exceptions     : not available
VCEI exceptions     : not available
```

## More info about Aboriginal Linux Mipsel

*(Binaries compiled on Aboriginal Linux will run on the embedded device, and it can run binaries retrieved from the device. I'm not happy with it as it doesn't have `make` and other tools I need for compiling larger applications)*

```
(mipsel:1) /home/wansview # cat /proc/cpuinfo 
system type     : MIPS Malta
machine         : Unknown
processor       : 0
cpu model       : MIPS 24Kc V0.0  FPU V0.0
BogoMIPS        : 1013.76
wait instruction    : yes
microsecond timers  : yes
tlb_entries     : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint : yes, count: 1, address/irw mask: [0x0ff8]
isa         : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented    : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers  : 0
core            : 0
VCED exceptions     : not available
VCEI exceptions     : not available
```

### LDD

Here's a screenshot with `ldd` ran against my hello world and against `unzip1` on both `aboriginal linux` and `debian mipsel`. Aboriginal Linux runs applications retrieved from the device just fine, and if I compile under Aboriginal Linux I can run the resulting binary on the embedded device. The reason I'm not content with Aboriginal is that doesn't have GNU `make` and other useful tools for larger applications, and no easy way to get them there.

[image]

Comment: "No such file or directory" is not the message when the ABI is not correct. Are you sure of this ? Also, I noticed you used "unzip1" for readelf and file but "unzip" when you tried running it.

Comment: @srd Sorry for the typo, I can confirmed it is definitely the same file I'm trying to run, and that is exactly the error I get.

Comment: A program compiled against one libc type will not run unless that libc is on the target (although the error will be something like `ld: cannot find libxxx.so`. You can easily see if this is the case with ldd (it is on aboriginal image). Please check if the same libc (and friends) are on the two devices, and that ldd does not complain in both cases.

Comment: @srd I've updated with a screenshot of `ldd` outputs. You seem to be right, one of them is looking for `libc.so.6` the other for `libc.so.0`. Are there any solutions at hand?

Comment: So it seems this is a matter of toolchain and runtime libc mismatch. I am not sure why the message "No such file or directory", but you must use a toolchain matching the run time environment on the target.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You clearly need a different toolchain. On your Debian-mipsel, your toolchain uses `glibc` while your target uses [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/).

So, maybe you would like to generate it by yourself using [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/):

```
wget http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/buildroot-2014.11.tar.gz
tar zxf http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/buildroot-2014.11.tar.gz
cd buildroot-2014.11
```

A trick to preconfigure for `mipsel`, `R1` without `soft-float` (my will, check yours):

```
cat <<_EOF > .config
BR2_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y
BR2_mipsel=y
BR2_ARCH="mipsel"
BR2_ENDIAN="LITTLE"
BR2_GCC_TARGET_ARCH="mips32"
BR2_GCC_TARGET_ABI="32"
BR2_ARCH_HAS_ATOMICS=y
BR2_mips_32=y
# BR2_MIPS_SOFT_FLOAT is not set
BR2_MIPS_OABI32=y
_EOF
```

Finish your choice in Buildroot `menuconfig`, but you can
also keep it like this with `save` and `exit`.

```
make menuconfig   # tweak options at your will,
make -j8          # takes 8 minutes on my machine
```

Then, your compiler can be found in `./output/host/usr/bin`

A real example:

```
echo '#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                   
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     printf("Hello World.\n");
     return 0;
 }' > hello.c
```

And compile it with your brand-new `uClibc` `GCC` compiler

```
output/host/usr/bin/mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc -o hello hello.c
```

A glimpse into the `hello` program: (didn't had time to fix my `ldd`...)

```
$ file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
$ strings hello | grep "lib.*so*"
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.0
```

It's done with the toolchain and compile your program.
Now that you have time :-) see what Buildroot offers :
a complete distribution (in `output/target/`) for embedded systems in many architectures.

**EDIT**: Better chance to execute

You can statically link your program in order to maximize the chances to run your code on any target.

```
$ output/host/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc -Wall -o hello -static hello.c
$ file ./hello
./hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

And now, as that static version doesn't depend anymore on any external lib (only uClibc, here), this **MIPS** executable can even run on my **x86_64** machine (thanks to [binfmt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt?id=HEAD) and [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)) :

```
$ uname -mo   
x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ./hello
Hello World.
```

Cheers.

Comment: Nice answer, but how can that executable run on x86 system when you are compiling for MIPS? If I understand correctly, these are different architectures - different cpu instructions. Or does your system defaultly invoke qemu for MIPS executables?

Comment: You're right, I have many (21) Qemu architectures installed + Java support + Python + Wine. In fact, Debian packages have done the job for me. In short, there are special files describing the magic (up to 128 bytes) and its associated file interpreter. Note that shebang `#!` is handled by `binfmt` directly in Linux Kernel [fs/binfmt_script.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/binfmt_script.c?id=HEAD#n17).

Comment: I see. A little edit would be recommended by me, so that other users that stumble upon this answer don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong but a simple fix (but not elegant way) in such cases could be to link the missing files to the existing ones:

```
ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.0
```

like in this situation:
https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/3083